# HTML5 video toggle audio tracks

Tags: html5-video

Given a video file with multiple audio tracks, I'm looking for a way to toggle the played audio stream during playback to save space and add multiple different translations to the same video file. I read about the `video.audioTracks` property, however, according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks) page it's only available in IE11+ and Safari browsers as of now. From what I've of about so far it might be possible to store the video without any audio tracks whatsoever and play the audiotracks separately (which would most likely lead to asynchronous playback). Are there any better ways of achieving this behaviour?